# When prototyping in Figma, can I make the frames automatically fit the device screen width?

Tags: interface-design, mobile, responsive-design, prototyping, figma

I'm new to Figma, just started learning it today, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I have a frame with a design that uses constraints to scale nicely to different screen widths. When I manually resize the frame, I can see the content align correctly. But when I preview it using Prototype on different devices, it seems to use the frame's initial size instead of fitting the device screen. So that the frame can be either too wide or too narrow depending on the device. Is there a way to make the frame width fit automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In the **Prototype** sidebar, **Device** section there is a list with several devices. Those are fixed pixel sizes. If your prototype dimensions don't match the device size you'll probably have scrolling.

Choose **Presentation** instead, each "slide" will fit the current Frame size; then you can have different Frame sizes in the same Prototype.

Note that it will still not fit the browser screen during the presentation mode; it is not responsive.